# Lagrange's basis function and Interpolation

Tags: interpolation

> Let $x_0,...,x_n$ be distinct real numbers and $l_k(x)$ be the
> Lagrange's basis function. $δ_n = ∏^n _{k=0}(x-x_k)$. Prove that
>
> a - $\sum^n_{k=0}x^j_kl_k(x) ≡ x^j$. for $j = 0,1,...,n$
>
> b - Let $P_n(x)$ interpolate $f(x)$ at $x_0,...,x_n$. Then $$P_n(x) = \frac{\sum^n_{k=0}f(x_k)/[\delta_n'(x_k)(x-x_k)]}{\sum^n_{k=0}1/[\delta_n'(x_k)(x-x_k)]}$$.

a - From the fact that $\sum^n_{k=0}l_k(x) ≡ 1$ since that the interpolating polynomial $p$ for $f=1$ is the sum $S$ of the Lagrange polynomials.  Since $f$ is a polynomial of degree $0$  and the interpolating polynomial is unique: $p = f$. As $p = s$, the sum of the Lagrange polynomials equals one. So from that since $l_k(x)\equiv 1$ then doesn't it follow from that fact it will be $\equiv x^j$? How can I show that using a proof?

b - No idea how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), you were on the right track. Suppose you interpolate $f(x) := x^j$ at the nodes $x_0, \ldots, x_n$. The interpolating polynomial is
$$
p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x_k^j \ell_k(x).
$$
Since, as you correctly say, the interpolating polynomial is unique (because the nodes are all distinct) and because $f$ is itself an interpolating polynomial of degree $\leq n$, we must have $p=f$.

For (b), first establish that $\delta_n'(x_j) = \Pi_{k \neq j} (x_j - x_k)$. Then, note that the $j$-th Lagrange polynomial may be written
$$
\ell_j(x) = \frac{\delta_n(x)}{\delta_n'(x_j) \ (x - x_j)}.
$$
So the interpolating polynomial may be written
$$
p(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n f_j \ \ell_j(x)
= \delta_n(x) \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{f_j}{\delta_n'(x_j) \ (x - x_j)}.
$$
Since $\sum_{j=0}^n \ell_j(x) = 1$, we have, using the expression of $\ell_j$ above
$$
1 =
\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{\delta_n(x)}{\delta_n'(x_j) \ (x - x_j)} =
\delta_n(x) \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{\delta_n'(x_j) \ (x - x_j)},
$$
and therefore
$$
\delta_n(x) =
\left(
\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{\delta_n'(x_j) \ (x - x_j)}
\right)^{-1}.
$$

The resulting expression for $p$ is called the *barycentric* formula. It turns out to be the most useful in practice since it can be computed as cheaply as the Newton interpolant and also updated relatively cheaply if new nodes are added.

A great paper about this form is that of [Berrut and Trefethen](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036144502417715). It also contains lots of pointers to the literature.

Comment: Thank you Dominique! For a I have edited to make it more distinguishable. Also for b what do you mean in your very last line "implies using the expression of $l_j(x)$ above $\delta_n(x) =
\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{\delta_n'(x_j) \ (x - x_j)}.$?"

Comment: @user60514 : I added a response to (a). Sorry there was an error in the last expression; I forgot to add a "1/..." Let me know if it's clear.

Comment: Yup, it is clearer. Thank you Dominique!